# gdb query xmm-registers, select representation

Tags: debugging, gdb, sse

Is there a way to select the desired representation of the xmm-register when printing it?

Example:

Up to now, I'm using f.e. `p/f $xmm0` which prints f.e.

```
$1 = {v4_float = {0, 0, 0, 0}, v2_double = {0, 0}, v16_int8 = {0 <repeats 16 times>}, v8_int16 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, v4_int32 = {0, 0, 0, 0},
  v2_int64 = {0, 0}, uint128 = 0}
```

Now I want to say GDB, "print the content ov `xmm0` but only the `v4_float` representation". Is  this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: `p $xmm0.v4_float`.  It works like a C union as far as GDB syntax.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry, didn't found the other post while searching for this.

Comment: That's fine, knowing the answer makes it much easier to find a duplicate :P